# Using Tweepy to email myself alerts. But the email content is accumulating every Tweet. I want it to overwrite

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, smtplib

I'm using Tweepy and streaming to track Tweets in real time. I'm trying to email the Tweets to myself whenever anyone posts with certain key words:

```
class StreamCollector(tweepy.Stream):

    def on_status(self, status):
        if not hasattr(status, 'retweeted_status') and status.in_reply_to_screen_name == None and status.is_quote_status == Fal\
se:
            if status.author.followers_count > 10:
                print('Twitter Handle: @'+status.author.screen_name)
                print('Followers:',status.author.followers_count)
                print('Tweet:',status.text)
                print('\n')

                mail_content = 'Tweet: {0}\nFollowers: {1}\nTweet Link: https://twitter.com/{2}/status/{3}'.format(status.text,\
status.author.followers_count,status.author.screen_name,status.id_str)

                message['Subject'] = '@'+status.author.screen_name   #The subject line                                          


                message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'plain')) #Create SMTP session for sending the mail                       
                session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) #use gmail with port                                              
                session.starttls() #enable security                                                                             
                session.login(sender_address, sender_pass) #login with mail_id and password                                     

                text = message.as_string()
                session.sendmail(sender_address, receiver_address, text)
                mail_content = []
                session.quit()

stream = StreamCollector(api_key,api_key_secret,access_token, access_token_secret)
stream.filter(track=["trigger words"])
```

This all works well  - except - the `mail_content` seems to be appended with every new Tweet - but I want it to be overwritten. Currently, each new email contains the `mail_content` of all the previous Tweets too.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears `message` is reused and you keep doing [`attach(payload)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.compat32-message.html#email.message.Message.attach).

Call [`set_content()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.set_content) instead.

```py
# message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'plain'))  # -
message.set_content(mail_content)                  # +
```

You should probably create a new `message` instance each time too.

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to use the .set() method vs .attach()

Also, you have

```
mail_content = []
```

I would reset this to a null string

```
mail_content = ''
```

Comment: `mail_content` is a local variable. There's no need to reset it.